# changing strings in array of char pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I have this two arrays, codeblocks doesn't give me any build error but whenever I run it, it gives "Segmention fault" and it shuts the program down I've debugged it and found out I can't change values from *names1* this way but changing *names2* this way works just fine, is there a way to make this work? If yes how do I make *troca* work for *names1*?

```
void troca(char* frase){
    unsigned i=0;
    while(*(frase+i)!='\0') {
        if(*(frase+i)=='O') {
            *(frase+i)='0';
        }
    i++;
    }
}

int main(){
    char *names1[]={"JOAO","MANUEL","ROBERTO","ZE"};
    char names2[][51]={"JOAO","MANUEL","ROBERTO","ZE"};
    unsigned i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        troca(names2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: google _string literals_

Comment: Not relevant here but I have read somewhere that two variables pointing to the same string literal might share the same memory. Changing one may change the other too..

Comment: Please post the *actual* code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Obviously this was not your code - if it does not compile it cannot produce a segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is:

`names1` is declared simply as an array of string pointers without other defined characteristics. Using string literals here will put the string literals into a section in your executable file which is **read-only**, because the compiler can this way re-use them. For example, when you use `char* a = "abc"; char* b = "abc";` then most likely `a` and `b` will have equal memory addresses as values. This means you can't modify them, so you get a "Segmentation fault" (another name for the same error is "Access Violation").

`names2` is declared as an array of arrays of chars. Assigning a string literal there will copy the data of the strings into the array, and since there is no `const` thing in play in your code, the array has to be mutable, so in turn your strings stored in the char arrays are mutable as well.